# Can I install Octave under Windows 7 without admin rights?

Tags: windows-7, installation, octave

Can I install Octave under Windows 7 without admin rights? There are similar questions on Linux, but this is about Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Pick a non system directory and unzip everything. It is true for any GUI for Octave such as [Xoctave](http://www.xoctave.com),QToctave, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for example within [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/install.html). Just download the appropriate Cygwin installer (32 or 64 bit) and run the setup*.exe with the '--no-admin' option. You can choose where your Cygwin environment and the packages should reside and can then choose packages to install. In the package overview you can find Octave in the math category or by using the search bar at the top.